# RegisterClientScriptBlock with async server-side Button click handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

Is it possible to invoke `ScriptManager.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock` in an async method?

Scenario: User enters a search value into a textbox and clicks a button. In the server-side button-click handler, code-behind sends a web request to a third-party webservice:

```
  protected async void Button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
         try
          {
               await QueryThirdPartyWebService(searchTerm);
               <snip>
           }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {

             Utils.DoAlert(this, ex.Message);
         }          
  }
```

When `QueryThirdPartyWebService` throws an exception, the code is branching correctly to the `catch` block.

The DoAlert method:

```
           string scriptContent = <snip>

           System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
            MyPage,
            typeof(System.Web.UI.Page),
            "errorMessage",
            scriptContent,
            true);
```

However, the `DoAlert` method is not doing anything. It does work properly in non-async contexts, but **not** when it is invoked from within an `async` method.  Stepping through the `DoAlert` method, there is no exception.

Answer (score 0):

RegisterClientScriptBlock is meant to work when sending a whole page of html and script to the client...the script will be inserted into the html and the popup box will work as the page loads on the client. In async you just get data and back and what you SHOULD do it have some javascript already at the client to handle the data that comes back and produce and alert. There's lots of code out there but basically the click event of the button fires off some javascript, which can be within your page if you like, and that javascript fires off a request to the server method. The javascript then analyses the response and fires off an alert.

To get started look at this and investigate along the lines of what I've said.

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_post.asp

You might like to look at Angular js, which is easy and great.

Comment: Are you saying that there's no way to make async requests to a remote web-service in *server-side* code and report an error back to the UI?  I am using an UpdatePanel with ASP.NET Ajax.  I have used pure HTML+ javascript in other applications, so I'm familiar with that approach, the one you're recommending.

Comment: Oh you're using an UpdatePanel ... hmm not sure about the details but behind the scenes it is still only changing part of the document that is on the client. This chappy says it doesn't work but then offers a way to make it work. ... http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Show-JavaScript-Alert-Message-inside-AJAX-UpdatePanel-in-ASPNet.aspx